# How to create wallet and address for Ethereum in Blockcypher Api

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using blockcypher Library and creating Api for Ethereum wallet and address but when i am passing ETH.main in

```
 $addressClient = new \BlockCypher\Client\AddressClient($apiContexts['ETH.main']);
```

> than it's giving undefined index error.

Unable to identify what is the issue and how can i create address and wallet through blockcypher Api.

Comment: Is this `$apiContexts['ETH.main']` returning undefined index?

Comment: Yes this is returning undefined index ETH.main

Comment: Okay. Can you add some more code?

Comment: equire_once (APPPATH . 'libraries/php-client-master/lib/BlockCypher/Client/AddressClient.php');
        include_once APPPATH . "libraries/php-client-master/sample/bootstrap.php";
        include_once APPPATH . "libraries/php-client-master/lib/BlockCypher/Api/Wallet.php";
        include_once APPPATH . "libraries/php-client-master/lib/BlockCypher/Client/WalletClient.php";
        $addressClient = new \BlockCypher\Client\AddressClient($apiContexts['ETH.main']);
        try {
            $addressKeyChain = $addressClient->generateAddress();
            $address = $addressKeyChain->address;

Comment: Please add it in your question only with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you not loaded the whole BlockCypher Library, you need to load the bootstrap.php or look at https://github.com/blockcypher/php-client/wiki/Making-First-Call for some starter instructions.

Comment: I have already loaded the bootstarp.php file but still this error is coming

Comment: How did you loaded/installed the BlockCypher Library, manual or composer?

Comment: It looks like you not loaded the Library correctly, try to use composer it creates a autoloader that you can use with CodeIgniter to auto-load all composer packages.

Comment: I have use it with composer but still same error is coming

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think the current library version for the toolkit needs to be adjusted to include ETH.

Open the file BlockCypherCoinSymbolConstants.php in the directory:

php-client/blockcypher/php-client/lib/BlockCypher/Core/BlockCypherCoinSymbolConstants.php

You can add ETH in the array that starts on Line 19, $COIN_SYMBOL_ODICT_LIST. The code I used is below. It works, but I'm not 100% sure of the correct values for 'pow', and 'address_first_char_list'

```
array(
        'coin_symbol' => 'eth',
        'display_name' => 'Ethereum',
        'display_shortname' => 'ETH',
        'blockcypher_code' => 'eth',
        'blockcypher_network' => 'main',
        'currency_abbrev' => 'eth',
        'pow' => 'sha',
        'example_address' => 'CFr99841LyMkyX5ZTGepY58rjXJhyNGXHf',
        "address_first_char_list" => array('B', 'C', 'D')
    )
```